# Can PyInstaller pack shared object files into executable?

Tags: python, tkinter, shared-libraries, pyinstaller

I've written a Python app which uses the tkinter module (among others) on Linux.

Python(3.10) with tkinter support was compiled by myself in a custom location (~/local), as well as the non-python dependencies like tk/tcl, libfreetype2, libpng, etc.

I've then packaged the script with PyInstaller using the `--one-file` option.
The resulting executable works if I execute it myself.

But copying it to another location and executing it as a different user leads to an
`ImportError: /home/*****/local/lib/libtcl8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied`, because of course that folder is not readable by that user.

I've tried bundling the .so file with both the `--add-data` and `--add-binary` option of PyInstaller, but none of it works. Even if I copy the files manually, it's still looking in the custom path.

Is there a way to specify to PyInstaller to package the needed shared object files into the executable or at least change any absolute path into a relative one, so I can bundle the files manually?

Comment: _but none of it works_, what do you mean ? Is the shared object not added to the 'build' or is the shared object not found while running the 'build' ?

Comment: It fails with the same error message as above. I assume the libraries are packaged, as the size of the single-file executable increases.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a .spec file created first time you have created an executable, Explicitly add all the files which need to be shipped with executable in the spec file data .

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html

For example , add datafiles and add it to datas in spec file :

```
data_files = [(os.path.join(some_path,some_file), '.'), ]

block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
         pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=data_files,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,... )
coll = COLLECT(...)
```

Now to generate pyinstaller executable use this spec file .

`pyinstaller somename.spec`

Do note that in your script dont directly load the files shipped in executable using explict paths instead load in this way , since pyinstaller during runtime in other environments dont pick the embedded files through explict paths but store in its file system so this take care of it  :

```
folder_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', some_path)
file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,some_file)
```